# Formatting for review instructions is off after loading second review item on iOS

Tags: bug, review, design, ios

Review queues have an instruction box at the top, e.g. for Late Answers:

> This is a **new user's answer to an old question**. Watch for hidden gems, non-answers, and spam.

When reviewing on iOS, everything looks fine for the first review item. However, once subsequent items are loaded into the page, the bold text becomes smaller than the rest:

[image: review instructions with small text]

Refreshing the page brings the font size back to normal:

[image: review instructions with normal text]